# Почему не срабатывает событие onClick в react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Есть компонента Star, которая затем используется в StarRating. Код Star:

```
import React from "react";
import { withStyles } from "material-ui-next";

const styles = {
  star: {
    cursor: "pointer",
    height: 25,
    width: 25,
    margin: 2,
    float: "left",
    backgroundColor: "grey",
    clipPath: `polygon(50% 0%, 61% 35%, 98% 35%, 68% 57%, 79% 91%, 50% 70%, 21% 91%, 32% 57%, 2% 35%, 39% 35%);`
  },
  selected: {
    cursor: "pointer",
    height: 25,
    width: 25,
    margin: 2,
    float: "left",
    backgroundColor: "green",
    clipPath: `polygon(50% 0%, 61% 35%, 98% 35%, 68% 57%, 79% 91%, 50% 70%, 21% 91%, 32% 57%, 2% 35%, 39% 35%);`
  }
};

const Star = ({ selected = true, classes }) => {
  return <div className={selected ? classes.selected : classes.star} />;
};

export default withStyles(styles)(Star);
```

И есть StarRating, в котором пытаюсь создать какое-то поведение на onClick

```
import React from "react";
import Star from "./Star";
import { Component } from "react";

class StarRating extends Component {
  displayName: "star-rating";

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      totalStar: 5,
      starSelected: 2
    };
    this.change = this.change.bind(this);
  }

  change(starSelected) {
    console.log(starSelected);
    this.setState({ starSelected });
  }

  render() {
    const { totalStar } = this.state;
    const { starSelected } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        {[...Array(totalStar)].map((item, index) => (
          <Star
            // key={index}
            onClick={() => console.log("mesage")}
            // selected={index < starSelected}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default StarRating;
```

Но onClick не выводит сообщения даже на консоль, то есть по сути не вызывается. Объясните пожалуйста почему не работает и что нужно поправить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

onClick здесь передается как пропс 
так как он навешен на компонент

внутри компонента star его нужно принять и вызвать

```
const Star = ({ selected = true, classes, onClick }) => {
  return <div onClick={onClick} className={selected ? classes.selected : classes.star} />;
};
```

но лучше его назвать onClick а например actionHandler